# How can I check if a BigDecimal is even?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've been trying to implement this for a while now, and I can't seem to make it wokr correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Define "evenness" if it isn't an integer.

Comment: Even means it ends with a 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8.

Comment: So `13.110` even and `13.11` is not? Can you clarify?

Comment: Is the mathematical value 2/9 even?  It doesn't "end" with anything.

Comment: I should clarify, Mystical you remove all trailing zeros. Since to store 2/9 as a BigDecimal you need to approximate anyways it depends on what your approximation is.

Comment: use the toString() method and get the last character, check for 0,2,4,6 or 8

Comment: I tried implementing that and failed.

Comment: So... is 13.110 "even"? Are you just trying to determine if it can be split into two equal parts? You can move the decimal point, you can get the decimal fraction, what specifically is the issue? What have you tried?

Comment: @jersam515 Without knowing your failure modalities, we're just doing it for you--can you ask a specific question?

Comment: Dave, I explained that with my definition the 0s had to be stripped. It appears I was wrong however about decimal values potentially being even/odd. Thanks everyone for taking a look. I will be upvoting all the answers I was given.

Comment: @jersam515 That's not the point: the question was "how do you want to deal with fractions", which is what Mysticial asked, and why I asked if you were trying to determine if the number could be split into two equal numbers. The answer you accepted implies that you don't even *care* about the fractional part, which you should have noted in the question or as a response to the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by 10 until you've reached the desired precision (number of digits after the .), then use bitwise comparison

```
public Boolean isEven ( BigDecimal decimal, int precision ) {
    double d = decimal.doubleValue ();
    int i = 0;
    while ( ++i <= precision )
        d *= 10;
    return ( (int) d & 1 ) == 0;
}
```

Comment: `BigDecimal`'s are used for specific reasons. Using `doubleValue()` is not a universally valid method.

Answer (score 5):

The term "even" does not generally apply to decimal numbers, but if you simply wish to test if the last digit of the decimal representation of a fractional number contains 2,4,6, or 8 then you can do the below:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("123.456");
BigInteger integer = decimal.stripTrailingZeros().unscaledValue();
boolean isEven = !integer.testBit(0);
```

This method avoids losing any precision or incurring any overflow as can happen when converting a BigDecimal to an int, long or double.

Answer (score 2):

`boolean isEven = ! decimalValue.toBigInteger().testBit(0)`

Comment: This only looks at the integer portion of the number, per the question comments it appears that a solution that also looks at the fractional portion is desired.

Comment: @increment1: from the comments that were there when I answered the question my understanding was that the OP wanted to discard the fractional part. It now appears otherwise. It's hard to answer a poorly formed question, and most of the time I don't even try. I regret doing so this time.

Comment: Completely understandable since I am not yet sure the question is clear to anyone.  I only commented since this was the accepted answer in case readers were not aware that converting the big decimal to a big integer would discard the fractional portion (although it is probably obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Only whole numbers can be even. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)
BigDecimal handles decimals, which are not even numbers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

If you must, you can convert the big decimal to the nearest possible Integer:

```
BigDecimal bd;
bd = 123.456;
int i;
// Convert the BigDecimal to an Integer
i = bd.intValue();
```

Or if you want to be alerted if information is being lost (the part after the decimal place) then try

```
try {
  i = intValueExact();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println( "Not a whole number: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Which will throw a `ArithmeticException` if information is lost.